# I need curl query to check connectivity of my Splunk

Tags: curl, splunk, splunk-query

I want to check connectivity of my Splunk with Curl command for that I am looking for curl query which will just refresh my Splunk web and returns 200 response.

Can anyone help me regarding this, It will be really helpful for me.

Thanks,
Anshu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if Splunk is up by hitting the logon screen.  Try `curl -k https://<host>:8000`.